# NgRx : Cannot add NgRx/store to my angular application V16

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

While trying to Add NgRx in my angular application popped an error in my cmd "ERESOLVE could not resolve".

Angular Versions:
"@angular/core": "^16.2.11",
"@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
"@angular/cli": "^16.2.8",

npm Version:8.11.0,
node version: v16.16.0,

Based on my other search in community, I tried uninstalling npm and update node, But still couldn't find a solution.
I tried ng add @ngrx/store@16 because my angular version is V16 but still facing same err.

[Error while @ngrx/store@16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdUhN.png)

Comment: can you please post the entire error message

Comment: attached link to the screenshot of error. If you need I can share .log file.